# How can I dynamically increase storage space for a program deployed on Solana using Solang?

Tags: solana-program, pda, solang, space, data-storage

I have a program that utilizes arrays and mappings, potentially requiring significant storage space.

Is there a mechanism to dynamically augment the storage space of the account that deployed the program in the event it exhausts its allocated space?

I am developing using Solang for Solana.